# Android BottomNavigationのまとめ方

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="#FFF"
    app:itemTextColor="#FFF"
    app:menu="@menu/footer_menu" />
```

一般的なBottomNavigationですが、これをすべてのActivityにコピペするのは格好悪いので、

```
    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    style="@style/Footer" />
```

このようにstyleにまとめたいのですが、`app:itemIconTint`などはどうすればstyleに記述できますか？

Answer (score 2):

こんな感じで app を無視して書くと動きます。

```
<style name="Footer">
    <item name="itemIconTint">#FFF</item>
</style>
```